# Compiling Cairo package from source on OS X

Tags: r, graphics, cairo

I'm having trouble compiling the Cairo package on CRAN from source on Mac (10.10.2) on R 3.1.3. I'm not sure what the error message means.

**Can anyone explain the below error message referring to a missing symbol?**

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Cairo', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Users/Simon/R/R64_Libs/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so':
  dlopen(/Users/Simon/R/R64_Libs/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so, 6): Symbol not found: _FT_Done_Face
  Referenced from: /Users/Simon/R/R64_Libs/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/Simon/R/R64_Libs/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
```

Relevant lines from `./configure` might include:

```
configure: CAIRO_LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.13/lib -L/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lfreetype -lz -lpng16 -lz -lXrender -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXext -lcairo
```

and

```
configure: CAIRO_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/cairo -I/usr/X11/include -I/usr/local/include/cairo -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.42.0/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.42.0/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/0.9.35_1/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.13/include/libpng16
```

Comment: This sort of problem shows up regularly on the r-sig-mac mailing list.  I recommend you search the archives to see what the "other" Simon suggests.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yes, thanks. Actually, this is not my first port of call and I did already look there. I do not see any references to `Symbol not found: _FT_Done_Face` in relation to compiling `Cairo` (or in any other context actually. If you know of such a post I'd appreciate a pointer!

Comment: So what Simon says is what did Simon say? Finally!